# Method of inserting a record( include the local current TIME) from Android to MySQL through PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql

In order to insert the current time to MySQL, I know there is a `now()` in MySQL.
However, I don't know is it a good practice to do it. My timezone is different from the server timezone, so I don't know how to convert it.
Also, I want to just display the Year/Month/Day in Android, Should I
1) use the PHP time function or
2) use the MySQL time function
so that it is easier for me to maintain.
Please give some idea

Answer (score 1):

Whichever one you end up using,  I'd recommend using the UTC time rather than a timezone-based stamp. **I would go with using NOW() inside of queries and time() otherwise. This way you end up with less "glue code" that does nothing but change the format of data.**

Afterward you can set a global to define the timezone the user is in, and shift the time when it is displayed. If you use UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) instead of just plain NOW(), you can simply add the UTC time to TIMEZONE_OFFSET * 60 * 60 (thats number of hours times 60 minutes times 60 seconds) to get the current time in the given timezone. Then just feed it to php's date() as the second parameter and you can format it however you like.

An added plus, this also allows things to be sorted chronologically when being submitted from different time zones.

You can ensure both PHP and MySQL are using UTC by doing this:

```
mysql_query('SET time_zone = "+0:00";');
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Comment: After the two scripts, I can insert using now()? But when I get back the data from database, how can I convert to my timezone and the format that I want (i.e. year/month)?

Comment: How does the data look when its stored in the DB?

Comment: Pass it to strtotime(), that function is magic for converting dates of any format into a unix timestamp. You can then pass this value to date() as the second parameter. Check out the docs on the date function here: http://php.net/manual/function.date.php (international link)